# Passing parameters vs Allocation inside function, memory-leak in java/android?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

2 Different ways of doing the same thing (i.e Fetching messages from Database)

- **Scenerio 1**

Calling Class:

```
ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
messages = Db.getAllMessage(messages);
```

Database Class:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllMessage(ArrayList<String> m) {
   m= /* get messages from DB */
   return m;
}
```

- **Scenerio 2**

Calling Class:

```
ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
messages = Db.getAllMessage();
```

Database Class:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllMessage() {
   ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
   temp = /* get messages from DB */
   return temp;
}
```

My Question is, in **Scenario 2**,

1. What will happen to **temp** ArrayList variable,
2. Will it remain in memory until the activity is destroyed ?
3. Is it a **Memory Leak**?

---

### **Edit:**

> In the talk video ***[Android Application Architecture (Android Dev Summit 2015)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlkJzgjzL0c&feature=youtu.be&t=1139)***, Adam Powell mentions that GC is your enemy and suggests to use Scenario 1 in case of Android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable itself will go out of scope and be deallocated (as the call stack shrinks).

The object that the variable points to (the ArrayList) still has another reference pointing to it, so it will not be collected.

It will go away when no more references (such as your `messages` variable or field) exists.

This is not a memory leak.

---

In both scenarios, it is pointless to create the empty ArrayList before calling the function (and you should be asking yourself what happens to it once you receive the new one, just like you worried about `temp`. Don't worry, it's only pointless, not dangerous or "leaky").

Do this instead:

```
ArrayList<String> messages = Db.getAllMessages();
```

Comment: Please can explain in a little more detail that what is harm in doing this?
**ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
messages = Db.getAllMessage();**

Comment: The harm is you are spending resources (cycles, memory) on  `new ArrayList<String>();`, let `messages` point to it and in the very next line, you are pointing `messages` elsewhere. The `ArrayList` you created first is not referenced anymore and is garbage collected. It is never used, and is not necessary for the second operation, so the resources you spent are wasted.

Answer (score 0):

The two scenarios are no different.

The empty array list on the r.h.s. in scenario 1 is immediately eligible for GC.

The reference to the temporary created by the database class in scenario 2 is passed back to the caller.  It's local to the database method, so that reference goes out of scope and its reference count drops by one.

Neither is a leak, unless the calling class hangs onto the reference that's returned from the database class for too long.

Comment: Define "immediately". Not before the method returns and the actual reassignment happens, right?

Comment: the GC runs on a separate thread; you don't know when it will run.  The reference count will be updated with the method frame is popped off the stack.